# How to get Objective C class by passing Swift calls to Objective C function

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, swift2, bridging-header

I have library developed in Objective C. In that library, one of my property expects the registration of my class. So that it will call the pre-defined method on that class. (Some what like delegate).

Below is my objective C property and how I set in swift class:

```
Builder.registerMapperClass(KeyMapper().self)
```

For now, I have passed `KeyMapper().self`, but this is not working. I also tried `KeyMapper()`. Because in Objective C, it is throwing error as below

```
-[PROJECTNAME.KeyMapper mapPropertyForKey:ForClass:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9911f22c60"
```

Here, PROJECTNAME is appended before the class name. Now, since this method will be called on Class which is not present with name `PROJECTNAME.KeyMapper` but `KeyMapper`.

So how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try doing just Builder.registerMapperClass(KeyMapper)?  using KeyMapper() will pass in an instance of the class, not the class itself

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: I tried that but it is giving a compile time error saying that KeyMapper.type should be given and we cant give direct class.

Comment: How about  let class = KeyMapper();  Builder.registerMapperClass(class.dynamicType)?

Comment: I tried with but with swift 2.0, it is giving me error as: PATH_TO_FILE/BaseService.swift:67:58: Cannot convert value of type 'KeyMapper.Type' to expected argument type 'KeyMapperAdapter!'

Comment: What parameter type does registerMapperClass take?